# Passing a command as an argument to another command

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

Hi so have some list of data which I've define as macros. Everything below are all in a package.

```
\newcommand{\testa}[0]{1/2/2/1,3/4/2/3}
```

I have many more of these predefined. I also have a command which I would like
to utilize these macros I've defined earlier.

```
\newcommand{\dosomething}[1]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x / \y / \a / \b in {#1} {
\draw[black,line width=0.1cm] (\a,\b) -- (\x,\y);
};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
```

But here is the problem. This is whats happening when I try to use them outside of the package.

```
% The following works
\dosomething{1/2/2/1,3/4/2/3}
% This however does not...
\dosomething{\testa}
```

I end up getting the error

```
! Missing = inserted for \ifnum
<to be read again>
                   /
```

There is clearly something that I am misunderstanding but I'm not sure what. I've tried searching for this problem but I couldn't find something to what I was looking for or I might have just too little understanding of latex to correlate it to my own problem. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You need to expand the argument before using it in the way you do.

Comment: Try `\expandafter\dosomething\expandafter{\testa}` (untested, however), as a possible way what @TeXnician mentioned....

Comment: Alright, I tested it out and im getting a new error "Missing Number, treated as zero"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you're going to use coordinates, you can expand the argument:

```
\newcommand{\dosomething}[1]{%
  \edef\dosomethingargument{#1}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \x / \y / \a / \b in \dosomethingargument {
      \draw[black,line width=0.1cm] (\a,\b) -- (\x,\y);
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
```

#### Full example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\dosomething}[1]{%
  \edef\dosomethingargument{#1}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \x / \y / \a / \b in \dosomethingargument {
      \draw[black,line width=0.1cm] (\a,\b) -- (\x,\y);
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\newcommand{\testa}{1/2/2/1,3/4/2/3}

\begin{document}

\section{Explicit}

\dosomething{1/2/2/1,3/4/2/3}

\section{Implicit}

\dosomething{\testa}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In case `\testa` can contain something dangerous for `\edef`, use

```
\edef\dosomethingargument{\unexpanded\expandafter{#1}}
```

What’s the trick? The macro `\foreach` expects the set of variables, followed by `in`; then it checks for a brace. If it finds it, `\foreach` interprets the text up to the matching closed brace as the set of items for the loop. Otherwise, the token after `in` should be a macro, which `\foreach` takes as the container of the items for the loop.

Thus with `\foreach \x/\y/\a/\b in {\testa}` the loop is performed over a single item. Conversely, `\foreach \x/\y/\a/\b in \testa` will perform the loop on all the items contained in `\testa`. By doing `\edef` we can always pass `\foreach` a macro.

Comment: Thanks! This really helped a lot :) . I was wondering if you could explain to me why I need to define it? I guess I just want to understand why latex was complaining to begin with and why \edef fixes that here.